# How can I call Javascript from C# code behind?

Tags: javascript, c#

I know the answer to this is all over the place, but I am just moving from desktop apps to web apps, and the current postings look like Greek to me.

My situation:

It is a web-based permit application for internal company use. The starting point is a grid of existing permits, or user can create a new one.

There are four states during the life cycle of the permit, and two "conditions" I have to consider (initial load of page with database values, and user clicking a button to progress the permit to the next state).

So on the initial OnLoad event I grab the db row for the row ID passed to the page (or null for new permit), and I populate some controls and hide/show certain `<div>` by setting class attributes according the the state stored in the db. I'm good so far.

OnLoad is not static, so all of this magic is performed in the C# code behind (where I am a lot more comfortable coding than Javascript) - there is a switch for the state and I call appropriate method to make the page look like I need it to. I'm good here also.

Now the fun begins - the user selects the next state from a drop-down and click a button. JavaScript picks up the click event and creates a partial model object with the new state and some remarks the user has entered in a textbox, then passes to a static method in the code behind, where a stored procedure is called and some db values get updated. This is working.

The last thing the static code behind method does is create a JSON string response with some data basically telling the page if the update was successful or not, and if successful, Javascript updates some controls, and hides/shows `<div>` areas.
My issue is why do I have code is two separate files that do the exact same thing? I don't care if server or client, can I put methods in ONE file that can be called for both conditions?

Since I am more comfortable in the code behind, I started there, but since my AJAX call is to a static method, I can't just call my C# methods to perform the hide/show on page load (since they actually touch the textboxes/`<div>` controls, they can't be static).

So now, I am looking for how to put the individual state-specific actions in the Javascript and call them from the code behind in my switch(state) method during OnLoad().

The standard answer is "you can't call Javascript from code behind", but then everyone shows an example using something about Register.this.that(a bunch of values go here), and they all seem to have the button click event in the code behind where mine is in the Javascript. My event is actually the OnLoad(), so in theory, same thing.

If this Register thing is the answer I am looking for, please don't just paste a line of code and say it is the answer. Take a step back and explain what is happening when (I'll have some example code you can add it to).

```
protected void OnLoad()
{
    // perform user checks to see what permissions the user has
    // parse incoming page for existing rowID
    if(rowID == null)
    {
    // new permit
    SetVisualsForNewPermit();
    }
    else
    {
      var permit = DataClass.GetPermit(rowID);
      switch(permit.State)
      {
        case A:
            SetVisualsPermitStateA(permit);
            break;
        case B:
            SetVisualsPermitStateB(permit);
            break;
        case C:
            SetVisualsPermitStateC(permit);
            break;
      }
    }
}

protected string UpdateState(PermitModel permit)
{
    // there is a lot more going on here,
    // but this is the basic idea
    try
    {
    var result = DataClass.UpdatePermit(permit);
    return JSON.ToString(result);
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    return JSON.ToString(ex.Message);
    }
}

private void SetVisualsPermitStateA(PermitModel permit)
{
    // state a means permit originated but has no approvals
    // set some textbox values
    // update the some combobox with approver names
    // show the <div> for first approver
    // enable both approve and reject button for first approver
    // hide other <div> areas
    //**********************************************************************
* instead of actually performing these specific actions here,
can I, at this point, make a call into the Javascript where there is a method that do these exact same actions?
* wondering about performance, how much network traffic is going back and forth in this method because of all of the different controls being manipulated from server code? Would it cut down on traffic to make one call to the client and have the client perform all of the manipulation?
}
```

Comment: You would do a lot better thinking about all the javascript as a completely different app. A browser doesn't know or care what back end stack is used to send what it consumes (html, css, scripts, media etc) and front end Javascript only knows the browser window environment it runs in that processes those resources. When used for requests like ajax...javascript only knows where and what to send/receive but not what happens at the other end

Comment: Hi, @charlietfl is right. In this case, you need an API Rest, in order to fulfill your requirements. You have to use AJAX, send the endpoint (where your C# code is working as a backend) and expect the result to parse in the frontend :)

Comment: How are you making the ajax call?  I've been using DevExpress and that tool makes it very easy to "call" javascript from code-behind (there is a client-side EndCallback event that can read from control properties (like passing parameters from C#)).  The event is fired when the server-side processing is complete.

Comment: when you refer as code behind are you working with Web Forms? if thats the case you just need to call Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page.GetType(),"ScriptId","script",bool for add script tag or not)